# Change GUI to be "Material"

Tags: android, material-design

I am developing an Android app. One page displays a list of persons (1st mockup). Clicking on a person then causes an dialog box to popup with detail information about the person (2nd mockup). (Note that the presentation in the app is cleaner than what is shown here).

What would I do to make this presentation in accordance with Material design?

[image: list of persons]
[image: details]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this list violates the google design. Dont they have a description on how lists should look like on an Android device? I recommend you to not display city and all that information but to concentrate on the names and if possible a picture. This humaises the list entries and also won't produce such a data overload

Comment: Ok, I can mimimize the information in the `ListView`. No photos of the humans available, though.

Comment: have you made any effort to look at the Material Design documents? UX StackExchange is not appropriate for outsourcing your design work, and this question is especially eyebrow-raising because the material design documentation actually includes screenshot of Contacts layouts.

Comment: Use a front-end development framework like Materialize (http://materializecss.com/) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material design definitely does have [guidelines for lists](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs), @Jonas. In short, the answer is typography and consistent spacing. There are also [guidelines for dialogues](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-content).